# Sql Server Insert a new row if 1 value does not exist in dest table

Tags: sql, insert

I have 2 tables, A and B. I want to insert the name and 'notInTime' into table B if that name IS NOT currently falling into the period between time_start and time_end.

eg: time now = 10:30

```
TABLE A
NAME TIME_START (DATETIME) TIME_END (DATETIME)
A 12:00 14:00
A 10:00 13:00
B 09:00 11:00
B 10:00 11:00
C 12:00 14:00
D 16:00 17:00

Table B
Name Indicator
A intime
B intime
```

If run the query should add the following to Table B

```
C notInTime
D notinTime
```

Comment: Which database are you using ? is 12:00 datatime or time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add those in time and those not in time to table_b

```
declare @now time = '10:30'

INSERT INTO TABLE_B(Name, Indicator)
select 
a.NAME, case when b.chk = 1 THEN 'intime' else 'notInTime' end
from 
(
select distinct NAME from TABLE_A
) a
outer apply
(select top 1 1 chk from TABLE_A 
where @now between TIME_START and TIME_END and a.Name = Name) b
```

Comment: Nearly but there's a bug caused by the fact i have multiple lines for each name with different start/end times. If 'now' is between any of these times then i want to add the line name, 'notInTime' to Table B. The problem here is that your sub query to select what to insert always finds at least one instance where the name does not fall within start/end. Using my exampel above, this query would add A, B, C and D into the table B because it finds '10:30' is outside of at least one of their start/end times.

Comment: Ignore above comment - this worked a gem. Thanks a million bud, really appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_B b (column_name_1, column_name_2)
SELECT 
'C', 
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_A a WHERE a.NAME = 'C' AND '10:30' BETWEEN TIME(a.TIME_START) AND TIME(a.TIME_END)) THEN 'intime' ELSE 'notinTime' END
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
'D', 
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_A a WHERE a.NAME = 'D' AND '10:30' BETWEEN TIME(a.TIME_START) AND TIME(a.TIME_END)) THEN 'intime' ELSE 'notinTime' END
```

Comment: Got solution below, apologies if i didnt try your solution., i looks like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Tried `BETWEEN`?

```
  INSERT INTO TABLE B 
 (SELECT DISTINCT
         name
       , 'notInTime'
    FROM A
  WHERE '10:30' NOT BETWEEN TIME(a.TIME_START) AND TIME(a.TIME_END))
```

Comment: Nearly but there's a bug caused by the fact i have multiple lines for each name with different start/end times. If 'now' is between any of these times then i want to add the line name, 'notInTime' to Table B. The problem here is that your sub query to select what to insert always finds at least one instance where the name does not fall within start/end. Using my exampel above, this query would add A, B, C and D into the table B because it finds '10:30' is outside of at least one of their start/end times.

Answer (score 0):

Much like @trapicki said, but no reason to hardcode the time.

```
insert
  into b
  (select distinct name,
                   'notInTime'
     from a
     where sysdate not between a.time_start and a.time_end)
```

Comment: Nearly but there's a bug caused by the fact i have multiple lines for each name with different start/end times. If 'now' is between any of these times then i want to add the line name, 'notInTime' to Table B. The problem here is that your sub query to select what to insert always finds at least one instance where the name does not fall within start/end. Using my exampel above, this query would add A, B, C and D into the table B because it finds '10:30' is outside of at least one of their start/end times.

Comment: I got the solution, Thanks for the help, appreciated.